# Store model form in session

Tags: python, django

I have one model form `ProductForm`. In a view I want to take the form data but want to save the form in another view. For this I tried to store it in session like this:

```
formToSave = ProductForm(request.POST,request.FILES)
product = formToSave.save(commit=False)
request.session['save_product'] = product
```

but getting the following error.

```
'Product' object is not serializable
```

I used django serializers like this:

```
request.session['save_product'] = serializers.serialize("xml", product)
```

but again got a new error:

```
'Product' object is not iterable
```

---

In my first view I have this code:

```
formToSave = ProductForm(request.POST,request.FILES)
product = formToSave.save(commit=False)
request.session['save_product'] = product
```

In the second view I am trying to get object from session and then trying to save it like this:

```
product = request.session['save_product']
product.save()
#saving product permanently
```

Could any one tell me how I can save the model form in another view?

Comment: Have you tried to just store the content of `request.POST` in the session and instanciate the form in the second view?

Comment: Also, why can you not save the form in the first view? That is how it is normaly done and how Django is prepared to work. Trying to do something very different could be an unnecessary complication.

Comment: Problem resolved by just storing the request.POST and request.FILES in session